# GnuTLS extension

Tags: c, linux, ssl, gnutls

I tried to add my own TLS extension using gnutls as  defined in this site  ( http://www.wikinology.cn/wiki/GnuTLS_Extension_Development_Notes),  so But let me explain step-by-step:

Note: i used gnutls-3.3.14 and extension named: SupportedAndAcceptedCertType.

1- **m4/hooks.m4**:

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING([whether to disable foobar support])
AC_ARG_ENABLE(SupportedAndAcceptedCertType,
    AS_HELP_STRING([--disable-SupportedAndAcceptedCertType],
        [disable SupportedAndAcceptedCertType support]),
    ac_enable_SupportedAndAcceptedCertType=no)

if test x$ac_enable_SupportedAndAcceptedCertType != xno; then
 AC_MSG_RESULT(no)
 AC_DEFINE(ENABLE_SupportedAndAcceptedCertType, 1, [enable SupportedAndAcceptedCertType])

else
 ac_full=0
 AC_MSG_RESULT(yes)

fi
AM_CONDITIONAL(ENABLE_SupportedAndAcceptedCertType, test "$ac_enable_SupportedAndAcceptedCertType" != "no")
```

2- **gnutls_int.h:**

GNUTLS_EXTENSION_SupportedAndAcceptedCertType=9999

3- **in gnutls_extensions.c:**

/ * Test * /

```
if ENABLE_SupportedAndAcceptedCertType
  ret = _gnutls_ext_register (&SupportedAndAcceptedCertType_ext);

  if (ret != GNUTLS_E_SUCCESS)
    return ret;
endif
```

/ * end Test */

4- **create SupportedAndAcceptedCertType.h in ext file:**

```
include "ext/SupportedAndAcceptedCertType.h"

extension_entry_st SupportedAndAcceptedCertType_ext = 

    {

    .name = "SupportedAndAcceptedCertType",
    .type = GNUTLS_EXTENSION_SupportedAndAcceptedCertType,
    .parse_type = GNUTLS_EXT_TLS,
    .recv_func = _SupportedAndAcceptedCertType_recv_params,
    .send_func = _SupportedAndAcceptedCertType_send_params,
    .pack_func = _SupportedAndAcceptedCertType_pack,
    .unpack_func = _SupportedAndAcceptedCertType_unpack,
    .deinit_func = NULL

    }
```

5- **create SupportedAndAcceptedCertType.c in ext file:**

```
include < gnutls_extensions.h >

int _SupportedAndAcceptedCertType_recv_params (gnutls_session_t session, const opaque * data,size_t data_size)
{
  return 0;
}

int _SupportedAndAcceptedCertType_send_params (gnutls_session_t session, gnutls_buffer_st* data)
{
  return 0;
}

int _SupportedAndAcceptedCertType_pack (extension_priv_data_t epriv, gnutls_buffer_st * ps)
{
   return 0;
}


int _SupportedAndAcceptedCertType_unpack (gnutls_buffer_st * ps, extension_priv_data_t * epriv)
{
   return 0;
}


static void _SupportedAndAcceptedCertType_deinit_data(extension_priv_data_t priv);
```

6- **in Makefile.am:**

```
if ENABLE_SupportedAndAcceptedCertType
libgnutls_ext_la_SOURCES += ext/SupportedAndAcceptedCertType.c ext/SupportedAndAcceptedCertType.h
endif
```

now based on the website "http://www.wikinology.cn/wiki/GnuTLS_Extension_Development_Notes" , i'm currently in the step "Update template files:

must be update these file:

lib/Makefile.in

lib/includes/gnutls/gnutls.h.in

how can i do this step ? and after this step the extension can i see my extension in the Handshake  (ClientHello and ServerHello)  ?

Thanks